# Apache beam, handling errors/side outputs with java 8 lambdas

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Can anyone provide an exemple on how to handle invalid inputs in apache beam using `Java8 Lambdas` in the same logic that we can find in this excellent blog post https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/01/handling-invalid-inputs-in-dataflow. Or do I have simply to use `ParDo` and `DoFn`

PS I'm using `beam 2.1.0`

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use DoFn. The transforms MapElements/FlatMapElements do not support side outputs.

Comment: Thx for your feedback